# Theoretically, can two hearts be connected with a pump between them?

Tags: technology, science-in-society

Like, if two hearts are outside of the bodies, could the two hearts be connected and function, using the blood from the people they came from, if the people had compatible blood types?  The hearts are still connected to the people, but damaged in, let's say, an attack.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding SE! Unfortunately, it's not clear what you're asking. Could you please be more specific in your question?

Comment: Seems answerable enough to me.

Comment: @dayton what’s weird to me is the “outside the bodies” part. What are the hearts’ jobs disconnected from bodies?

Comment: Are you [Odd from Writing.SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/48423/23927)? How come you're using a different, unregistered account?

Comment: @courtney If your question gets put on hold, that’s ok... you can edit the question to clarify our confusion and then click the “request reopen” button. Going on hold helps us get better worded questions (and you’ll get better answers with a bit of patience).

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, but you wouldn't**

We already have better technology.  A [cardiopulmonary bypass machine](https://www.texasheart.org/heart-health/heart-information-center/topics/a-heart-surgery-overview/) is used for open heart surgery.  While the surgeons are performing open heart surgery, the patient's heart has to be stopped.  So obviously it can't be keeping them alive during that time.  Their circulatory system is hooked up to a machine, which pumps the blood for them.

If someone's heart is damaged such that they would need this kind of setup, we already have better treatment options.  And if the world you're building doesn't have medical technology advanced enough to do this - well, it's probably *harder* to do what you're proposing.

1) There isn't any real gain in power - there's 2 hearts now, but they have twice as much work to do to keep both people alive.

2) If the heartbeats aren't exactly in sync, it will cause effects similar to [ventricular dyssynchrony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ventricular_dyssynchrony).  Basically, the two pumps waste energy being out of phase with each other.

Comment: Plus we can [piggyback](https://news.stanford.edu/news/2004/october20/med-Heart-1020.html) hearts anyway